# It has been developed vs It is being developed

Tags: meaning, grammar, progressive-aspect

What is the difference between the following sentences?

> It has been developed
>   vs
>   It is being developed
>
> It has been held
>   vs.
>   It is being held

- Which tense is "is being" used here and when do we use it?
- Is there any difference between "It **is being held**" and "It **is helding**"?